getting the watchlist for all friends on plex using Python-PlexAPI
Any hint on how to receive the watchlist for all the users on my plex server. I am creating a auto delete based on some rules, one rule is that the movie should not be deleted if it is on a users watchlist.
I am having trouble since all the watchlist related stuff is on MyPlexAccount.
lexapi.myplex.MyPlexAccount have all the methods needed for my user but lexapi.myplex.MyPlexAccount.users() returns plexapi.myplex.MyPlexUser that do not have any usefull data.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
